# Accessibility: How to use multiple LABEL elements for one INPUT item correctly (via ARIA, etc.)?

Tags: html, input, label, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a two-sided mobile menu drawer that relies on a hidden checkbox for switching/toggling between its two sides.

There are two LABEL elements, one on each side of the menu drawer. Each LABEL, via its FOR attribute, references the ID of the hidden INPUT checkbox. Clicking a displayed LABEL thus checks the INPUT checkbox and causes the menu to switch sides (via CSS). A distillation of the HTML is:

```
<ul class=main-menu>
    <li>
        <input id=toggle-drawer type=checkbox title="hidden checkbox">
        <label for=toggle-drawer>See Sub Menu</label>
        <ul class=sub-menu>
            <li>
                <label for=toggle-drawer>See Main Menu</label>
            </li>
            <li>Sub-menu item 1</li>
            <li>Sub-menu item 2</li>
            <li>Sub-menu item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Main Menu item 1</li>
    <li>Main Menu item 2</li>
    <li>Main Menu item 3</li>
</ul>
```

It is, in fact, perfectly valid HTML to have multiple labels that reference the same input item.

See https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1 :

> "More than one LABEL may be associated with the same control by
>   creating multiple references via the for attribute."

However, the WebAIM WAVE (Web Accessibility Evaluation Tool) browser extension flags the two labels as an error, stating,

> "A form control should have at most one associated label element. If
>   more than one label element is associated to the control, assistive
>   technology may not read the appropriate label."

As a remedy, it goes on to state:

> "If multiple form labels are necessary, use aria-labelledby."

aria-labelledby seems not to apply to my case, as it would be put on an INPUT item that is referenced by a DIV, etc.

Is there an ARIA or similar mark-up method I can use to satisfy this accessibility audit? I do not wish to alter my HTML structure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although it is perfectly valid HTML, having two labels will cause issues with NVDA and possibly other screen readers where it will only read one label.

This is why WAVE suggests you use `aria-labelledby` as that is designed to take multiple elements and can combine them (in the order you list them).

It is perfectly valid to use this on an `input`, also note that `aria-labelledby` will override any associated `<label>` elements using `for="id"`

One thing you could do is use the less often used `aria-describedby` to associate the second label and ensure that the reading order is correct.

In the example below it would read 'See Main Menu, See Sub Menu' as it will read the `<label  for="toggle-drawer">` first and then use the `aria-describedby="toggle-drawer-label"` to add additional information.

The only down side is that it may read the input information in between the `<label>` and the `describedby` label.

```
<ul class=main-menu>
    <li>
        <input id="toggle-drawer" aria-describedby="toggle-drawer-label" type=checkbox title="hidden checkbox">
        <label id="toggle-drawer-label">See Sub Menu</label>
        <ul class=sub-menu>
            <li>
                <label for="toggle-drawer">See Main Menu</label>
            </li>
            <li>Sub-menu item 1</li>
            <li>Sub-menu item 2</li>
            <li>Sub-menu item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Main Menu item 1</li>
    <li>Main Menu item 2</li>
    <li>Main Menu item 3</li>
</ul>
```

### The recommended way

I would recommend simply using `aria-labelledby="label1 label2"` as that is the accepted method and will result in the most consistent results, obviously it means you need to add `id` attributes to both labels so that is the trade off.

**Note** that using `aria-labelledby="label1 label2"` and associating the fields with `for="toggle-drawer"` on both labels has the added benefit of correctly linking the labels so that you can click on either label and it will focus the `<input>`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed response. The recommended way is the only solution that works with the menu mechanism, so it seems the right one to employ. However, when I apply it to the HTML, the WAVE browser extension still throws an error about multiple labels. Here's what it states: "A form control has more than one label associated with it.
Ensure that at most one label element is associated to the form control. If multiple form labels are necessary, use aria-labelledby." Somehow, it's not satisfied. Is there additional markup that might be necessary?

Comment: Sounds more like a problem where it doesn't recognise the use of `aria-labelledby` when you also use a `for=""` on them. I would ignore as you have remedied the problem it warned you about by using the `labelledby` to override. Remove the two `fors` just to test that the error goes away and then put them back in and ignore.

Comment: Yep, removing the "for" attributes allows the HTML to pass the WAVE validator, but of course, it prevents the checkbox mechanism from working. I'll have to contact the makers of the extension to let them examine this case to improve their algorithm.

Comment: Instead of relying on WAVE here, you can inspect the accessibility tree using the dev tools in Chrome and Firefox. These will tell you the computed accessible names, regardless of the exact markup method used to set them up. The accessibility tree is the real structure which assistive tech users interact with, whereas WAVE is a tool which is more geared towards assessing coding practice.